# Is it possible to run a model in a Coral Dev Board in a way in which it doesn't ocuppies the whole screen?

Tags: tpu, google-coral

I'm trying to build a setup in which I run my models on the Coral Dev Board locally, meaning that I can only access the shell directly from the monitor I have attached to the Dev Board, but I found out that once I run the model I can't get access to the shell in order to stop the model from running.
I was wondering if there was any way I could minimize the model view or to access the shell while I'm running the model

Answer (score 0):

You could try using something like `screen`
https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/